# Плагин Sublime Text

Tags: php, sublime-text

Верстаю в **Sublime Text 3**. Был плагин, который показывал функции PHP, а название плагина вспомнить не могу. Может кто посоветует?

Comment: у меня опечатка __METHOD__

Comment: Он? https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter

Comment: Да это оно большое спосибо